# Query Transform

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I need help on transforming query, How can I rewrite this query with join into a query with subquery. Both the original and transformed query should return same results. I just need to see their differences in terms of autotrace and explain plan. Thank You.

```
select emp.employee_id, count(jh.department_id) as ID_Count
from employees emp left outer join
     job_history jh
     on emp.employee_id = jh.employee_id
group by emp.employee_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
select emp.employee_id, 
       (select count(jh.department_id)
          from job_history jh
         where emp.employee_id = jh.employee_id
         ) as ID_Count
from employees emp;
```

I hope I helped!

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you @Goran Kutlaca. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, @Sho :) Nevertheless, I would appreciate if you'd tag this answer as a correct one, if it is ;)